# How can i do this animation in Flutter with Google Maps markers

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-markers, flutter-animation

[The video example in YouTube.](https://youtu.be/dq-ksuP0zEc)
I want to animate markers on [Google Maps](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter). I used [flutter animarker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker), but it don't work for me. Is there any other way to do what i need?